# I can't graph this for the life of me

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Countless hours staring at this changing everything around, I'm going crazy!   I'm lost.  I can't get this data to plot.   I feel I am very close, but no cigar.  I want there to be a line vs. time.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd #this is how I usually import pandas
import sys #only needed to determine Python version number
import matplotlib
import numpy as np 
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.dates as md
import dateutil
#print('Python version ' + sys.version)
#print('Pandas version ' + pd.__version__)
#print('Matplotlib version ' + matplotlib.__version__)
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default') 
pd.set_option('display.line_width', 5000) 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 60) 
force = pd.read_csv(open('press.csv','rU'), encoding='utf-8',       engine='c', header=None)
force.columns =  ["presst", "units", "pressm", "units2", "date", "time", "nothin"]
#plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
#plt.xticks( rotation= 80 )
#ax=plt.gca()
#xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
#plt.figure()
#for i in range(len('presst')):
#    plt.plot('time'[i], 'presst'[i])
#plt.show()
    print(force)
      presst    units1 pressm   units2      date      time     nothin
0     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:14     NaN
1     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:14     NaN
2     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
3     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
4     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
5     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
6     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
7     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
8     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
9     40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
10    40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
11    40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15     NaN
12    40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:16     NaN
13    40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:16     NaN
14    40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:16     NaN
15    40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:16     NaN
16    40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:16     NaN
17    40.0      lbf   100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017        13     NaN
```

Comment: Your code is a bit chaotic. (1) Setting `plt.figure()` after adjusting the axes does not make any sense. (2)  `len('presst')` returns 6, because the word presst has 6 letters. (3) `plot('time'[i], 'presst'[i])` does not work at all, since  you are actually trying to to plot the letter `p` against the letter `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
force['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(force['date'] + " " + force['time'])

force.set_index('datetime').presst.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying that before and I get an undefined name df....do I not have a library installed?

Comment: No.  That's my bad.  We use `df` to name dataframes.  You have it as `force`.  I've updated my post.

Comment: @J.Stahl How can a straight like look so beautiful?

Comment: I think you were trying to say line, there is beauty in the simplicity!